# Change Subject Data Type from Text to Long Text

Tags: fields

Is there a way to change the Subject field data type from Text Area (255) to Long Text Area on the Case object? The Subject field is a standard field.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cant change the standard Subject field. The subject field is intended to be a summary anyways, if you need more space you should utilize the Description field.